# Dependency vulnerability scanner for Conda?

Tags: python

Python's `pip` dependency manager is supported by a number of vulnerability scanners (e.g., Snyk, Gitlab's gemnasium, PyUp), but I have not found such a service for scanning dependencies defined in Conda's `environment.yml`.

Is there a service out there which supports Conda? Can I somehow massage an existing service into scanning these deps?

---

Conda: https://conda.io/docs/

Anaconda: https://anaconda.org/

Comment: there is a scanner of a particular _environment_  : https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-cve . It doesn't seem very fancy or even maintained, but perhaps it will get you on the right path?

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?